# Can I use the twitterAPI to identify the country of an account?

Tags: api, twitter

Is there a way to use the twitterAPI to find out if the owner of an account is located in Korea or Japan? ??
Currently, time_zone and lang are not set, so I can't confirm it well.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to do this via the API, or otherwise, really. Unless the owner of the account choses to geotag their Tweets - and that is optional on their side - then there may be no indication of the location of the user.